# Is there a way to be able to get a list of someones instagram followers without using InstaLoader in python?

Tags: python, instagram

I am trying to get a list of instagram followers for a daily statistical tracker. I was using InstaLoader and using the login credentials of a Instagram account, but for obvious reasons it keeps getting flagged for suspicious activity. I would like to completely remove logging into an account from the program but I have not found any alternatives

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit more hardware intense, but you can try to webscrape your follower number using something like selenium. If you use selenium-stealth or undetected_chromedriver I don't think you will get flagged. Im not sure but I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For some reason instagram doesn't load all followers in web version - selenium may be not helpful for scraping. Check out chrome extension IG Exporter, it stores all followers to CSV. As for logging into/out issue, check using Chrome profile with selenium - it will allow to leave user logged in (if it suits you in terms of security)